# jQuery mousewheel prevent default only in some cases

Tags: jquery, events

I've got simple page that has horizontal scrolling with `jquey.mousewheel` plugin and `$('html, body').mousewheel();`

Inside I've made horizontal scrolling and used `event.preventDefault();` - to prevent scrolling it vertically. But I have one class of divs with comments sections witch I want to be scrolling vertically when that div is `hovered` and mousewheel is used. But prevent default block it.

So how to disable global horizontal scrolling and enable normal werical inside div only when mouse is hovering it?

Answer (score 1):

Please consider using this code:

```
$('html, body').not(".nomousewheel").mousewheel();
```

This selector will not apply the function on the elements with class `.nomousewheel`.

Comment: Its not working, I even dont know why. I've done it with if (!$('#notmousewheel').is(':hover')) -the problem is that it wokrs only with #id, and no with classes what is not quite future thinking solution.